# Load the same module from different packages in Python

Tags: python, import

I have a package with multiple packages inside, and inside each a main.py module. 
Inside this module there is a `register()` function. I need to execute this function for each module!

```
Plugins
| 
 -A
|   |
|    -main.py -> register()
| 
 -B
   |
    -main.py -> register()
```

I thought on exploring the plugins path and loading the module using `importlib`, but when I package the application using py2exe I get an error saying that the `plugins` folder doesn't exists on execution time. Since it was never requested by the normal way "import ...", py2exe didn't include the directory on the package.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could alias your imports, e.g.:

```
from A import main as mainA
from B import main as mainB

mainA.register()
mainB.register()
```

...or:

```
from A.main import register as registerA
from B.main import register as registerB

registerA()
registerB()
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the packages that can exist in the plugin path...

Comment: It's not really a plugin if it has to be built when the application is built.

Comment: there are 2 folders for plugins, the core one, and the user one... The core plugins are built-in but they use the same plugin-system than user ones.
Internal plugins are in fact the base application!